# PHP, MVC: Rewrite rule for index page

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make the index page to respect the rewrite rule defined in .htaccess (or to rewrite the path in index.php with the default route defined in my routes file : rewrite.php).

Why, you may ask? I'm creating a kind of MVC project in PHP (I said 'kind of', because I do not use a Framework like Zend, I just implemented the MVC idea into pure php). So, instead of pages I have views. I do not have an index.php  file in my project (nor index.html... actually no index file at all). I'm rewriting all url-paths with the help of .htaccess file and then I use the controllers further to manipulate the model or display in views. 
Why not using an index.php page, you may then ask? Like I said, I'm using controllers to do stuffs. By using an index page I do not have the ability to manipulate models and views via controllers, because the physical pages have priority and the url rewriting rules are ignored. So, if someone goes to root page (http://www.domain.com/) the server will automatically display the index page as it is and I do not want to duplicate the logic of first page (getting and displaying data), just for using an index page.

Maybe this is stupid, but I've tried to change the default directory page (DirectoryIndex in .htaccess) to nothing (didn't work, as I expected). :)

That being said, I've excluded the index page. It works well, it shows data like it should do, but at a closer look, I see the browser actually receive '403 Forbidden' on the root page.

In ASP.NET MVC the existence of Default.aspx is also mandatory (for the same reasons, I think). But in the Default page the http context path is rewritten with the default route defined in Global.asax. The question is how do I do that in PHP? (or any other suggestion is welcomed)

You can see the page that I'm talking about here : www.clubclio.eu (as you can see, the data is well displayed, yet you receive 403 Forbidden).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by renaming the rewrite.php file (the route file defined in .htaccess) to index.php

So, to answer my own question but to help others too, make sure you have the route file defined as the index file (name it index.php or define DirectoryIndex in .htacctess as the name of your route file).

Maybe this is obvious for others. :)